# Is there a way to check if a file has an extension, and if not append that extension?

Tags: python, path, pathlib

My code is supposed to create `.csv` files and it does, but it doesn't always append the `.csv` extension to the end of the file even though it is a `.csv`. I just want to check the final output file before it is returned to the user, and append `.csv` if it doesn't have that extension.

Here is the snippet I'm using currently:

```
if not path_to_file.endswith('.csv' or '.json'):
    path_to_file.append('.csv')
else:
    return path_to_file.absolute()
```

This throws an error: `AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'endswith'`.

Comment: If you have the filename as a string, you can check if it ends with .csv: `if filename.endswith('.csv'):...`

Comment: You could check out the str.endswith() method.

Comment: How are you saving that file? How are you generating the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with paths calls for using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). You don't even need to check for the current extension and simply use the [`with_suffix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) method:

```py
from pathlib import Path

print(Path("/a/b/c").with_suffix(".csv"))
print(Path("/a/b/c.csv").with_suffix(".csv"))
```

Will both give:

```
\a\b\c.csv
\a\b\c.csv
```